# Susy and responsive images

Tags: susy-compass, compass-sass

i don't understand something with grid mixin.Actually i use this code, but only work on mobile, on desktop, the image container doesn't get the full size.

```
.vue-diapo-hp-img{
     //@include set-container-width();
       img{@include adaptable-img;}
       @include at-breakpoint ($mobile){
          @include set-container-width();
       }
       @include at-breakpoint ($desktop){
         @include set-container-width();
         //@include span-columns($desktop);
       }
       @include at-breakpoint ($tablet){
           @include set-container-width();
       }
}
```

The html code is (drupal views source):

```
<div class="vue-diapo-hp-img">     <img class="imagefield imagefield-field_diapo_home_pano" width="990" height="204" src="http://sandboxd6-1.vmsbx/sites/sandboxd6-1.vmsbx/files/diapo_home/site-date-yyyy/site-date-ww/gabarit-diapo-home-er.jpg?1383819992">  </div>
<div id="transparency"></div>
<div id="contenu-diapo">
<h2></h2></div>
```

what can i do to get both breakpoint works ? what is the difference between

`@include set-container-width();` and   `@include span-columns($desktop);` for example ?

you can see it in action : http://d6sbx1.pfdev.tk/

thanks

EDIT1: modified code after explaination

```
.vue-diapo-hp-img{
       clear: both;
       img{@include adaptable-img;}
       @include at-breakpoint ($mobile){
          @include set-container-width();
       }
       @include at-breakpoint ($desktop){
        @include set-container-width();
         //@include span-columns($desktop);
       }
       @include at-breakpoint ($tablet){
          @include set-container-width();
       }
}
```

this doesn't do responsive image on mobile but give full width on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

`set-container-width` sets a width (or max-width) value based on the total-columns, plus grid-padding. `span-columns` sets the width of an item inside that container - often a relative width unless you have set your `$container-style` to `static` (which you haven't, in this case). `span-columns` also applies floats, and margins to align items on your grid. With a static grid and no grid-padding, they might return the same width, but they are built to calculate different objects, so they use different logic underneath.

But it looks to me like you already have a container in place, and you simply want to span the full width of that container - in which case you don't need either one. All block elements, including your image-wrapper, span full width by default. If you need to clear a float above, you can just `clear: both` to do that. And sine you want that at every breakpoint, there's no reason to use media-queries either:

```
.vue-diapo-hp-img{
  clear: both;
}
```

That should be all you need. At most, you could add `width: 100%` if (for some reason) it's not spanning the full width.

Comment: yes i've a global container on #general, but i don't understand how can i do responsive layout if i don't set values for each breakpoint as you seem to say...see edit1 for my modified code. Actually it works on webkit but not on IE and FF,when i resize the window to fit a mobile size..

Comment: Because you want full-width at all breakpoints, and because full-width is relative (so it can flex to fit any container), you don't need to change the size at each breakpoint. All breakpoints should simply get `100%` (which is the block default). Code you set outside any breakpoint will be used at all breakpoints, so drop those breakpoints entirely and just let the block do it's default thing. You really don't want to be setting container width on internal elements. That mixin is *only meant for containers*.

Comment: ok i understand your logic.So i just need to set size for parents elements and not for children isn't it ? but i don't understand why,if i set a size for only one breakpoint, all breakpoints are affected..

Comment: There may be times where you need to set size on child elements, just not if they are always full-width. Similarly, setting size for one breakpoint may not always affect others. It depends how your breakpoints are set up. You can set breakpoints with just min-width (in which case they will affect larger ones, or just max-width in which case they will affect smaller, or both in which case they will not affect others at all. But, in this case, you can use *no breakpoints* which will affect *everything*.

Comment: ok,just test with only the image-width:100%, and it appears this rule is applied only for connected user on drupal 6 !! since the beginning this append my learning of susy.. :(

Comment: is it possible to use this: `@include set-container-width($desktop/2);` with something like `@include set-container-width($desktop/2.15);` ?

Comment: i get this : WARNING: Susy works best with integer column-spans.
    For partial-columns, you may need to finesse the math by hand using functions directly.
         on line 61 of /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/susy/_functions.scss
how about using decimal number to divide container ?

Comment: Why are you still trying to use `set-container-width`? I really don't understand what you are doing, or how Drupal 6 has anything to do with the CSS. I'm sorry.

Comment: sorry, since i understand what `set-container-width` is for, it's really more simple to build my grid.My question was about the ability to do math into mixin with variables in susy.